# How to add to Spring/Hibernate architecture creation of JPA 2 Criteria queries?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

My architecture includes creating the SessionFactory bean in the application-context.xml:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"  
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
</bean>
```

Then I have the base Repository class injecting  this sessionFactory.

```
public class GenericRepositoryImpl<T extends BaseEntity> {

@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
```

The injection allows me to work with Named Queries, for example

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Transactional(readOnly = true, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
protected List<T> findByNamedQuery(String queryString) {
    // return entityManager.createNamedQuery(queryString).getResultList();
    return sessionFactory.openSession().getNamedQuery(queryString).list();
}
```

I am using Hibernate 5 and Spring 4. How to add to this architecture the capability to use JPA 2 Criteria queries?

Comment: You can just inject the persistencecontext instead and use that directly.
 @PersistenceContext
 protected EntityManager em;

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use the `Criteria` inside your `openSession` provided by the injected SessionFactory? I'm not sure if it's possible to do in that version:

```
Criteria = sessionFactory.openSession().createCriteria(Foo.class);
```

Comment: This method creates Hibernate criteria that is different from JPA 2  criteria API

Answer (score 0):

Inject Entitymanager directly to your GenericRepository as below.

```
@PersistenceContext
protected EntityManager entityManager;
```

and start creating criteria

```
entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder()
```